# json values via checkboxes

Tags: javascript, json, checkbox

in FE I have two searches. One search is by text: If I type in the post code the correct output from json works fine. But I want to have a second search by checkboxes. There you should be able to find the right company by product.

But I am not good enough in Javascript to find out how it works.
I've made a jsfiddle. Would be aweseome if you could help.

You can see my code below and in a better way in https://jsfiddle.net/kzayjn4m/

```
"productLines": ["Heimanwender", "SOHO", "Small Business" , "Medium Business", "Enterprise", "Öffentliche Hand", "Gesundheitswesen"],

document.getElementById('hero').addEventListener('onchange', function(e){
if(e.which == 13){
    searchStores();
}
```

});

```
function searchStores() {
var foundStores = [];
var zipCode = document.getElementById('zip-code-input').value; 
var place = document.getElementById('hero').checked;
 
 if (place) {
     stores.forEach(function (store, index) {
         var places = store.productLines;
        
            if (places == true) { 
            foundStores.push(store);
        
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a click event on each input and if the function has been given a product value, see if the store products array contains that value

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#hero input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            searchStores(this.value)
        }
    });
})

function searchStores(product) {
    var foundStores = [];
    var zipCode = document.getElementById('zip-code-input').value;

    if (product) {
        stores.forEach(function (store) {
            if (store.productLines.includes(product)) {
                foundStores.push(store);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I tried to make it happen but it is not working. I used this code in html <input type="checkbox" onclick="searchStores()" name="test" value="test"> test
 and your code. Maybe it is an issue with '#hero input' in queryselector all. Do all the values that appear in the json have to be listed here? thanksk for your help